# Cannot Add Foreign Key Constraint - I Checked almost everything

Tags: mysql, foreign-keys

okay, so im having a weird issue with this foreign key constraint.
The data type is Int(11) and all tables and databases are using utf8_general_ci but I'm still getting an issue! the only table that inherited the Medicine_ID is the First Aid table.

Here's my schema:

tbl_Medicine

```
+--------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field        | Type        | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+--------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Medicine_ID  | int(11)     | NO   | PRI | NULL    |       |
| Brand_Name   | varchar(45) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| Generic_Name | varchar(45) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| Countable    | int(11)     | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
+--------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
```

tbl_batch

```
+---------------+---------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field         | Type    | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+---------------+---------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Batch_ID      | int(11) | NO   | PRI | NULL    |       |
| Purchase_Date | date    | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
+---------------+---------+------+-----+---------+-------+
```

tbl_Stock

```
+-----------------+---------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field           | Type    | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+-----------------+---------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Stock_ID        | int(11) | NO   | PRI | NULL    |       |
| Medicine_ID     | int(11) | NO   | PRI | NULL    |       |
| Batch_ID        | int(11) | NO   | PRI | NULL    |       |
| Expiration_Date | date    | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| Quantity        | int(45) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| Unit_Price      | int(11) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
+-----------------+---------+------+-----+---------+-------+
```

tbl_inventory

```
+--------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field        | Type        | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+--------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Inventory_ID | int(11)     | NO   | PRI | NULL    |       |
| Building     | varchar(45) | NO   | PRI | NULL    |       |
| Stock_ID     | int(11)     | NO   | PRI | NULL    |       |
| Medicine_ID  | int(11)     | NO   | PRI | NULL    |       |
| Quantity     | varchar(45) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
+--------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
```

tbl_Activity

```
+--------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field        | Type        | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+--------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Activity_ID  | varchar(10) | NO   | PRI | NULL    |       |
| Purpose      | varchar(50) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| Organization | varchar(50) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| Reciever     | varchar(50) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| Recieve_Date | date        | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| Act_Date     | date        | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| Validator    | varchar(10) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
+--------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
```

Heres the creation query:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `csb_inventory`.`tbl_batch` (
  `Batch_ID` INT(11) NOT NULL COMMENT '',
  `Purchase_Date` DATE NULL DEFAULT NULL COMMENT '',
  PRIMARY KEY (`Batch_ID`)  COMMENT '')
ENGINE = InnoDB
DEFAULT CHARACTER SET = utf8;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `csb_inventory`.`tbl_medicine` (
  `Medicine_ID` INT(11) NOT NULL COMMENT '',
  `Brand_Name` VARCHAR(45) NULL DEFAULT NULL COMMENT '',
  `Generic_Name` VARCHAR(45) NULL DEFAULT NULL COMMENT '',
  `Countable` INT(11) NULL DEFAULT NULL COMMENT '',
  PRIMARY KEY (`Medicine_ID`)  COMMENT '')
ENGINE = InnoDB
DEFAULT CHARACTER SET = utf8;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `csb_inventory`.`tbl_stock` (
  `Stock_ID` INT(11) NOT NULL COMMENT '',
  `Medicine_ID` INT(11) NOT NULL COMMENT '',
  `Batch_ID` INT(11) NOT NULL COMMENT '',
  `Expiration_Date` DATE NULL DEFAULT NULL COMMENT '',
  `Quantity` INT(45) NULL DEFAULT NULL COMMENT '',
  `Unit_Price` INT(11) NULL DEFAULT NULL COMMENT '',
  PRIMARY KEY (`Stock_ID`, `Medicine_ID`, `Batch_ID`)  COMMENT '',
  INDEX `fk_tbl_Stock_tbl_Medicine_idx` (`Medicine_ID` ASC)  COMMENT '',
  INDEX `fk_tbl_Stock_tbl_Batch1_idx` (`Batch_ID` ASC)  COMMENT '',
  CONSTRAINT `batch`
    FOREIGN KEY (`Batch_ID`)
    REFERENCES `csb_inventory`.`tbl_batch` (`Batch_ID`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
  CONSTRAINT `medicine`
    FOREIGN KEY (`Medicine_ID`)
    REFERENCES `csb_inventory`.`tbl_medicine` (`Medicine_ID`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
ENGINE = InnoDB
DEFAULT CHARACTER SET = utf8;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `csb_inventory`.`tbl_inventory` (
  `Inventory_ID` INT(11) NOT NULL COMMENT '',
  `Building` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL COMMENT '',
  `Stock_ID` INT(11) NOT NULL COMMENT '',
  `Medicine_ID` INT(11) NOT NULL COMMENT '',
  `Quantity` VARCHAR(45) NULL DEFAULT NULL COMMENT '',
  PRIMARY KEY (`Inventory_ID`, `Building`, `Stock_ID`, `Medicine_ID`)  COMMENT '',
  INDEX `fk_tbl_Inventory_tbl_Building1_idx` (`Building` ASC)  COMMENT '',
  INDEX `fk_tbl_Inventory_tbl_Stock1_idx` (`Stock_ID` ASC, `Medicine_ID` ASC)  COMMENT '',
  CONSTRAINT `building`
    FOREIGN KEY (`Building`)
    REFERENCES `csb_patient`.`tbl_building` (`Building`),
  CONSTRAINT `stockitem`
    FOREIGN KEY (`Stock_ID` , `Medicine_ID`)
    REFERENCES `csb_inventory`.`tbl_stock` (`Stock_ID` , `Medicine_ID`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
ENGINE = InnoDB
DEFAULT CHARACTER SET = utf8;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `csb_inventory`.`tbl_firstaid` (
  `FirstAid_ID` VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL COMMENT '',
  `Activity_ID` VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL COMMENT '',
  `Quantity` SMALLINT(6) NOT NULL COMMENT '',
  `Inventory_ID` INT(11) NOT NULL COMMENT '',
  `Medicine_ID` INT(11) NOT NULL COMMENT '',
  PRIMARY KEY (`FirstAid_ID`, `Activity_ID`, `Inventory_ID`, `Medicine_ID`)  COMMENT '',
  INDEX `activity_id` (`Activity_ID` ASC)  COMMENT '',
  INDEX `fk_tbl_firstaid_tbl_inventory1_idx` (`Inventory_ID` ASC, `Medicine_ID` ASC)  COMMENT '',
  CONSTRAINT `activity_id`
    FOREIGN KEY (`Activity_ID`)
    REFERENCES `csb_inventory`.`tbl_activity` (`Activity_ID`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
  CONSTRAINT `fk_tbl_firstaid_tbl_inventory1`
    FOREIGN KEY (`Inventory_ID` , `Medicine_ID`)
    REFERENCES `csb_inventory`.`tbl_inventory` (`Inventory_ID` , `Medicine_ID`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
ENGINE = InnoDB
DEFAULT CHARACTER SET = utf8;
```

I have read alot of threads regarding the same issue and tested them out.
I made sure that im using the same table_type, collation, and data_type. I even checked all other tables that are related that might have been causing the issue but no good. I was able to successfully add foreign keys to firstAid but only the Medicine_ID is the one failing.

help? xD

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you have `tbl_building` on before create `tbl_inventory`.

Comment: already did. somehow its not root. though thanks for the heads up. I checked on all my tables and found some of them has foreign constraint active but different in varchar size.